# Is there a way to downgrade edition of already installed Visual Studio 2010 (trial)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to change it from Ultimate to Professional? Is it possible without complete reinstall or at least without downloading another install image (we have too slow Internet connection)?

Comment: No.  Weekends were made to deal with slow internet connections.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid not. If you go to [Visual Studio's Website](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us) you might be able to download all of the files at your local library. If you don't have a laptop you can download to a 4 gigabyte flash drive - libraries usually have Wifi, wired internet, and computers that you can use for free.

Note: Be aware of time limits when using the library resources. You wouldn't want to get cut off when the download is 95%. Also, some libraries have reservations for computers and fees - check online ahead of time.